# If $E$ has positive measure, then prove that there exists $h \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|(E+h) \cap E| > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $E$ has positive measure, then prove that there exists $h \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|(E+h) \cap E| > 0$. I tried doing this by contradiction but cannot seem to find my way about the argument.

Any hints or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you actually mean $h \neq 0$ since clearly $\lambda(E) > 0.$

Comment: Do you have the Lebesgue Density Theorem?  If not, do you have the continuity of the Lebesgue Integral?  If not, do you have the Lebesgue Integral in general?  If you have the Density Theorem then this exercise is very direct; consider that the hint.  In fact, it's true for some *rational* $h \neq 0$.

Comment: @Actually Fritz, Yes sorry, we are assuming $h \neq 0$.

Comment: @John Samples, unfortunately, we do not have any of those ...

Comment: Can you prove that $h \mapsto \lambda((E + h) \cap E)$ is continuous? You can first assume that $E$ is an interval, then a general open set and extend this to general measurable sets by regularity. Do you see why this would solve your problem?

Comment: Fritz's idea is also my idea if you don't have any of the above tools.  It's obviously true for $E$ a closed interval, then generalize to finitely many closed intervals, and finally to measurable sets by approximating them with your intervals.  You will have to use a statement such as "if $E$ has positive measure, then its measure is positive on some compact interval" at some point.

Comment: I will try this and update you on my work. Thank you again for helping me out!

Comment: I tried the idea you guys mention, but did not get too far ... Could someone provide a bit more details? I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I find it is difficult to show the function is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If $E$ has positive measure then there exists an interval, say $I$ such that $m(E\cup I)>\frac{2}{3}m(I)$.
(Of course much more can be said about points of density of $E$ but we do not need it here).
Fix this interval $I$. Now, if $E-E$ does not contain a neighborhood of $0$ then there is a decreasing to zero sequence, say $x_{n}$ such that $E+x_n$ is disjoint with $E$. In particular, the set $I\cap E$ would be disjoint with $(I+x_n)\cap (E+x_n)$. However, $E+x_n$ is just a shift of $E$ so $m((I+x_n)\cap(E+x_n))> \frac{2}{3}m(I+x_n)$. Clearly, $m(I+x_n)=m(I)$. Now, this is not possible since for $x_n$ sufficiently small (i.e. $x_n< \frac{1}{6}m(I)$ ) we would have two disjoint sets contained in a small perturbation of $I$ ( add and subtract $x_n$ from I boundaries) each having measure larger than $\frac{2}{3}$ of $I$.
So, $E-E$ contains a neighborhood of $0$ which is the same as to say that $m(E\cap(E+h)) > 0$ for $h$ small enough.

Comment: How do we know there exists such a sequence $x_n$?

Comment: Sorry, a typo ... should be " if $E-E$ does not contain a neighborhood of $0$ then ..."  Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I see, I am still a bit confused on the argument, wouldn’t $E-E = \emptyset$?

Comment: @Blaze $E-E$ is not literally set subtraction. We define for two sets $A,B$ , $A-B = \{a-b : a \in A, b \in B\}$. Try to see that $[0,1]-[0,1] = [-1,1]$ using this definition, for example. Related is the [Theorem of Steinhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem) which in fact seems to be proved in this post.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove the statement for bounded $E$. So suppose $E$ is bounded.

Note $\int\int 1_E(y)1_E(y-h)dydh = \int 1_E(y)\int 1_E(y-h)dhdy = \int 1_E(y)|E|dy = |E|^2 > 0$.

So, there exists $h$ with $\int 1_E(y) 1_E(y-h)dy > 0$. But this integral is $|E\cap (h+E)|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we are not supposed to use any integrals for this question.

Comment: @Blaze You should have said that in your question.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify, is there any way to do this not using this strategy?

Comment: @Blaze do you know the lebesgue density theorem

Comment: I do not. My professor said that we do not need any "fancy" tools to solve this problem.

Comment: @Blaze what do you know? just the definition of measure? and some basic properties like additivity?

Comment: yes that is all really. Not much to work with...