# Let $E ⊆ R$ be a measurable set with |E|> 0. Prove that there exists $a ∈R, a\not= 0$, such that $|(E + a) ∩E|> 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-sets

> Let $E ⊆ R$ be a measurable set with $|E|> 0$. Prove that there exists $a ∈R, a\not= 0$, such that $|(E + a) ∩E|> 0$.

To prove this statement, we will use the fact that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, meaning that for any measurable set $E$ and any real number $a$, we have $|E+a| = |E|$. Using this property, we can show that if $|(E+a) ∩ E| = 0$ for all $a ∈ R$, then $|E| = 0$, which is a contradiction to our assumption that $|E| > 0$. I don't how to go further... Help please

Comment: @sein That is very very false.

Comment: @sein: This need not be true. There are sets with positive measure but still no-where dense.

Comment: @sein the irrational numbers don’t have an interval yet have positive measure.

Comment: can you help me to figure out, what to do

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025748/if-e-has-positive-measure-then-prove-that-there-exists-h-in-mathbbr-suc

Comment: I am not understanding that steps because we have not learn that much... can you tell me what other way can I do.. because I think,  if the measurable set itself is bounded, and we can usually write unbounded sets as the countable union of bounded sets

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider the function $$f(x)= \int 1_E(y)1_{(x+E)}(y)dy=m(E\cap (x+E))$$

Then $f$ is continuous and $f(0) =m(E) >0$

Then there exists $N_{\delta}(0) $ such that $f>0 $ on $N_{\delta}(0) $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\int \int\chi_E(t-a)\chi_E(t)dtda>0$ by Fubini. Hence, there exists $a$ such that $ |(E+a)\cap E|=\int\chi_E(t-a)\chi_E(t)dt>0$.

Comment: we have not learn it yet.. but I think  if the measurable set itself is bounded, and we can usually write unbounded sets as the countable union of bounded sets

Comment: do u think, what I am thinking is correct..

Comment: It is enough to prove the result for bounded $E$ but how does that help?  @dismay

Comment: sorry, what you trying to say, I am not getting.. can u please explain me briefly please!